# Pycharm cannot recognize cv2 but still usable

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I recently compiled the `OpenCV 4.4.0` with `CUDA` and `Python3` bindings following [this](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-4-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/) instruction. I install it to a virtualenv in Anaconda, and it works in Anaconda Prompt. But as I want to use it in `Pycharm`, the code `import cv2` is underlined with the hint (just underlined, not run yet):

```
No module named cv2
```

Even though I could import errorless and use it anyway. And then there's no "hint info" as my cursor was on the code e.g. `cv2.imread()` (normally there would be hints about input name and format etc.). So the problem should just be that Pycharm couldn't recognize it.

Could anyone enlighten me a little? Thanks!

[image: interface]

Answer (score 1):

Emmm I've solved it myself in a stupid way.

Since the problem is we only have the `.pyd` binding file, we need to make it a *python package* with *reference* files in it, like what we'd get from a normal cv2 module from `pip install`. So I just:

- create a new virtual env
- `pip install opencv-python=4.4.0.42` (or another version you desire)
- copy all files except for the `.pyd` file to the target virtual env. In my case it's located in `[PathToAnacondaEnvs]\MoVis_gpu\Lib\site-packages\cv2\`, so that `__init__.py` will make cv2 as a legitimate python package, and other files would add reference for it.

Not elegant, but it works :)

Comment: do you still have opencv cuda working after this replace ?

Comment: @lucians Yes, I used its DNN module for some direct inference.